# invariant violation element type is invalid

Tags: react-native

Guys I need to define a simple component in RN, but I keep getting this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK44q.jpg)

and this is my simple component code:

```
export default class Welcome extends Component {   
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
}
```

and the way I import it into my page(Intro.js):

```
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
    render() {
        return (
            <Welcome name="Sara" />
        );
    }
}
```

Finally I call the page including the component(Intro.js) in my app.js like this:

```
import { Intro } from './app/screens/Intro.js';

export default class App extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <Intro />
        )
    }
}
```

version I'm using:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.49.3
```

Appreciate your answers

Comment: Can you share more code from App.js ?

Comment: yes, I've edited my question

Comment: How do you know the error is related to Welcome? The screenshot shows an issue with App.js line 70. Are you using `ReactDOM.render()` ?

Comment: no I'm not, I'm just importing react and using render() as u see in the code. I guess this error is related to the component bcuz when I insert normal code I'm getting no errors and the page renders well. I get this error only when I call components.

Comment: What do you have in App.js line 70? Where is this code located `<Welcome name="Sara" />` ?

Comment: I edited my question so u can see the file I'm calling <Welcome /> in. I'm getting error on app.js line 75 which is the line I'm calling <Intro />

Answer (score 3):

As i can see in your code

```
export default class Welcome extends Component {   
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
}
```

You had use  which is html tag not a react natine element or component.
So this may be the reason for the error.
You can use  this code.

```
export default class Welcome extends Component {   
  render() {
    return <Text>Hello, {this.props.name}</Text>;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, did this correction, but still getting the same error

Comment: Can you show code of your App.js, as per screen shot it indicates  that error occors from line number 71 in App.js